# Textarea border in IE and Edge

Tags: css, textarea

I have a textarea styled and in chrome it appears fine with flat even borders all the way around, however in edge and IE it has a darker border on the left and upper sides (as shown in the picture below).  I'm assuming this is some kind of shadowing, how can this be removed?
[image: IE and Edge Border Issue]

The CSS I'm using for the text box is...

```
.textarea-rounded {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #95a5a6;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to default `border-color` of Edge. You can explicitly set `border-color` for this to make the same cross-browser border color.

```css
.textarea-rounded {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: #95a5a6;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 0);
  border-color: #808080; /* new */
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea-rounded"></textarea>
```